# Better way to parse and search a string?

Tags: python, rust

I have been looking to speed up a basic Python function which basically just takes a line of text and checks the line for a substring. The Python program is as follows:

```python
import time

def fun(line):
    l = line.split(" ", 10)
    if 'TTAGGG' in l[9]:
        pass  # Do nothing

line = "FCC2CCMACXX:4:1105:10758:14389# 81 chrM 1 32 10S90M = 16151 16062 CATCACGATGGATCACAGGTCTATCACCCTATTAACCACTCACGGGAGCTTTCCATGCATTTGGTATTTTCGTCTGGGGGGTGTGCACGCTTAGGGGATAGCATTG bbb^Wcbbbbccbbbcbccbba]WQG^bbcdcb_^_c_^`ccdddeeeeeffggggiiiiihiiiiihiiihihiiiihghhiihgfgfgeeeeebbb NM:i:1 AS:i:85 XS:i:65 RG:Z:1_DB31"

time0 = time.time()
for i in range(10000):
    fun(line)
print time.time() - time0
```

I wanted to see if I could use some of the high level features of Rust to possibly gain some performance, but the code runs considerably slower. The Rust conversion is:

```rust
extern crate regex;
extern crate time;
use regex::Regex;

fn main() {
    let line = "FCC2CCMACXX:4:1105:10758:14389# 81 chrM 1 32 10S90M = 16151 16062 CATCACGATGGATCACAGGTCTATCACCCTATTAACCACTCACGGGAGCTTTCCATGCATTTGGTATTTTCGTCTGGGGGGTGTGCACGCTTAGGGGATAGCATTG bbb^Wcbbbbccbbbcbccbba]WQG^bbcdcb_^_c_^`ccdddeeeeeffggggiiiiihiiiiihiiihihiiiihghhiihgfgfgeeeeebbb NM:i:1 AS:i:85 XS:i:65 RG:Z:1_DB31";    
    let substring: &str = "TTAGGG";
    let time0: f64 = time::precise_time_s();

    for _ in 0..10000 {
        fun(line, substring);
    }

    let time1: f64 = time::precise_time_s();
    let elapsed: f64 = time1 - time0;
    println!("{}", elapsed);
}


fn fun(line: &str, substring: &str) {
    let l: Vec<&str> = line.split(" ")
                .enumerate()
                .filter(|&(i, _)| i==9)
                .map(|(_, e) | e)
                .collect();

    let re = Regex::new(substring).unwrap();    
    if re.is_match(&l[0]) {
        // Do nothing
    }
}
```

On my machine, Python times this at 0.0065s vs Rusts 1.3946s.

Just checking some basic timings, the `line.split()` part of the code takes around 1s, and the regex step is around 0.4s. Can this really be right, or is there an issue with timing this properly?

Comment: You're compiling a regex in each invocation of `fun`, which is not going to be particularly fast. In the Python code, you're not using regexes at all, so it's a bit of an unfair comparison. Since you're just doing substring search, you should probably just use [`str::find`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/primitive.str.html#method.find).

Comment: You should also provide the commands you're using to compile and run your program. For example, are you compiling with optimizations enabled?

Comment: It may not mean anything for performance (though your code does allocate memory a `Vec`, so perhaps it does make a difference) but: For `line.split()`, it would be way easier to do `line.split(" ").nth(9).unwrap();`

Comment: Using python regex doesn't make much difference, although this is because the regex will only be compiled once regardless if its in a loop. Is it possible to pass a compiled regex to a function in rust? I'm just using cargo run from the terminal. Ill have a go with the suggestions, thank you. I also liked the .filter.map.collect because I can grab a few fields from the string..

Comment: @kezzos `cargo run` does not run the program with optimizations. Try using `cargo run --release`. In general, it is a good idea to provide enough information in your question such that others can reproduce your result. Otherwise, it's hard to diagnose the problem.

Comment: Wow that's a big improvement. I am only just getting into rust and was not aware of the --release option. The python code is pretty lightweight so is probably interpreted fairly efficiently to C code anyway. If you would be kind enough to show me your solution with the regex compiled once/substring match Shepmaster, we can get this question accepted :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As a baseline, I ran your Python program with Python 2.7.6. Over 10 runs, it had a mean time of 12.2ms with a standard deviation of 443μs. I don't know how you got the very good time of **6.5ms**.

Running your Rust code with Rust 1.4.0-dev (`febdc3b20`), without optimizations, I got a mean of 958ms and a standard deviation of 33ms.

Running your code with optimizations (`cargo run --release`), I got a mean of 34.6ms and standard deviation of 495μs. **Always do benchmarking in release mode**.

There are further optimizations you can do:

Compiling the regex once, outside of the timing loop:

```
fn main() {
    // ...
    let substring = "TTAGGG";
    let re = Regex::new(substring).unwrap();

    // ...

    for _ in 0..10000 {
        fun(line, &re);
    }

    // ...
}

fn fun(line: &str, re: &Regex) {
    // ...
}
```

Produces an average of 10.4ms with a standard deviation of 678μs.

Switching to a substring match:

```
fn fun(line: &str, substring: &str) {
    // ...

    if l[0].contains(substring) {
        // Do nothing
    }
}
```

Has a mean of 8.7ms and a standard deviation of 334μs.

And finally, if you look at just the one result instead of collecting everything into a vector:

```
fn fun(line: &str, substring: &str) {
    let col = line.split(" ").nth(9);

    if col.map(|c| c.contains(substring)).unwrap_or(false) {
        // Do nothing
    }
}
```

Has a mean of 6.30ms and standard deviation of 114μs.

Answer (score 3):

A direct translation of the Python would be

```
extern crate time;

fn fun(line: &str) {
    let mut l = line.split(" ");
    if l.nth(9).unwrap().contains("TTAGGG") {
        // do nothing
    }
}

fn main() {
    let line = "FCC2CCMACXX:4:1105:10758:14389# 81 chrM 1 32 10S90M = 16151 16062 CATCACGATGGATCACAGGTCTATCACCCTATTAACCACTCACGGGAGCTTTCCATGCATTTGGTATTTTCGTCTGGGGGGTGTGCACGCTTAGGGGATAGCATTG bbb^Wcbbbbccbbbcbccbba]WQG^bbcdcb_^_c_^`ccdddeeeeeffggggiiiiihiiiiihiiihihiiiihghhiihgfgfgeeeeebbb NM:i:1 AS:i:85 XS:i:65 RG:Z:1_DB31";

    let time0 = time::precise_time_s();
    for _ in 0..10000 {
        fun(line);
    }
    println!("{}", time::precise_time_s() - time0);
}
```

Using `cargo run --release` on stable (1.2.0), I get about `0.0267` as compared to about `0.0240` for Python (CPython, 2.7.10). Given Python's `in` on strings is just a C routine, this is reasonable.

Impressively, on beta (1.3.0) and nightly (1.4.0) this decreases to about just `0.0122`, or about twice the speed of CPython!

Comment: Interesting that your Rust version doesn't beat Python! What version of Rust and Python are you using?

Comment: 1.2.0 (from the Arch repos). IIRC the match machinery was recently updated, so it's quite possible the betas/nightlys are ahead.

Comment: @Shepmaster Yep, I just downloaded `multirust` and beta and nightly are way faster.

Comment: True that, switching to nightly gave me almost 50% speed increase without changing a thing